# Having Trouble sending long message Python Logs From Google Cloud Functions Out Of Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, papertrail-app

I was wondering whether cloud functions has restrictions to export logging from python out of Google Cloud Platform for long messages (over 1500 characters).

The below are [multiple examples from Papertrail](https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-centralized-logging-from-python-apps/#examples) on how to send log messages from Python, but the one I tried is below which worked sending messages to Papertrail on Google Compute Engine, but did not work on Google Cloud Functions. Google Cloud Function instead logs them in Google Cloud Operation Logging Service.

```
import logging
import socket
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()

    def filter(self, record):
        record.hostname = ContextFilter.hostname
        return True

syslog = SysLogHandler(address=('logsN.papertrailapp.com', XXXXX))
syslog.addFilter(ContextFilter())

format = '%(asctime)s %(hostname)s YOUR_APP: %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(format, datefmt='%b %d %H:%M:%S')
syslog.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(syslog)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info("This is a message")
```

In particular, it seems that for the above code, the address I placed on the handler does not work in Google Cloud Function if the message I pass is too long.

```
syslog = SysLogHandler(address=('logsN.papertrailapp.com', XXXXX))
```

Is this normal or my cloud function has some issues? 
Is there a way I can pass an address in my python logging within Google Cloud Functions that can be compatible for long messages?

Comment: Does your Cloud Function have a billing account attached to it? Free tier Cloud Functions are not able to communicate with external URLs.

Comment: Hi, I tried to debug more extensively and it appears it happens for only long messages to be sent at once. For instance, less than 100 characters, it gets send both to Google Cloud Operations Logging and Papertrail, but if its over 1500 characters, it does not get passed on Papertrail. This does not happen when running it in Google Cloud Compute Engine. Will update the question to limit the scope of the issue.

Comment: I can confirm, after extensive debugging, it seems it doesn't export it to an address if the message is long. My example was the following. I had a string of 1300 characters. I tried to split it up by 100,200,400,800,1050 characters and it all was exported well both on Papertrail and Google Cloud Function. However, once I tried 1200 characters, only the first split (1200 characters) of the message was not printed on papertrail, but the second split (100 characters) was printed on papertrail. I am not sure the reason why.